# Altering Wordpress Download Response Headers

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, executable, httpresponse

Currently I have a wordpress site on the local development server that has a download link on it. On this download link is a setup.exe/softwarename.msi installer package that has been compressed using the built in microsoft iexpress tool.

The problem? Wordpress is sending the download as application/x-msdownload. This is triggering all sorts of malware alerts in Chrome and other browsers. A simple change of the response header to application/octet-stream will probably fix the problem. However, I'm not sure how to go about changing it so that wordpress is sending the proper response header rather than some age-old application/x-msdownload header. Is there a way I can redirect the link using htaccess to change the header?

Can anyone help me? I'd rather not have customers turned away because of a fake malware alert.

Thanks!

EDIT: I managed to use AddType to change the returned type. I still have the same problem though. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with a simple redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^old-url\.php$ http://www.domain.com/new-url.php [NC,R=301,T=application/octet-stream ]
```